# Fill the form with information from PDF file with reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, pdf

i'm trying to implement new feature to my app where i can import specific .PDF file and fill the form on my website with information from that .PDF file, i tried extracting text from .PDF file with some libraries like PDF.JS & pdf-parse and non of them work as i expected, so I'm posting this question to get some ideas of how could I approach this problem. The .PDF will always have the same template only informations like (name, address, etc.) will change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you're using the libraries in a wrong way, would be helpful to share what you tried doing

Comment: I was not able to use these libraries on front-end, so i solved the problem by sending file to the back-end and then i extracted text into object and sent to client side... Thanks for help!